# how can i slove the given issue while not disturb the built site in drupal

Tags: drupal-content-types

I completely developed a website in Drupal 8 and then, finally delete 3 content types, because those required for me further, so due to this may give me an error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebuilding the site registry? If you are using drugs you can run

```
drush rr
```

https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/registry-rebuild/registry-rebuild/

Edit: Rebuilding the registry only works for drupal 7 and lower. You can try a cache rebuild

```
drush cr
```

Comment: thank you so much, but the project is on live server and i have no experience to work drush on live server. i just clear all cache and i don't know how to rebuild it through drupal admin panel